# Show that a determinant equals the product of another determinant and a polynomial function without calculating

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, multilinear-algebra

Show without calculating the determinant, that

$$
    \det\left(\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{1}+b_{1}x & a_{1}-b_{1}x & c_{1}\\
    a_{2}+b_{2}x & a_{2}-b_{2}x & c_{2}\\
    a_{3}+b_{3}x & a_{3}-b_{3}x& c_{3}\\
    \end{bmatrix}\right) 
    = 
    -2x 
    \det\left(\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{1} & b_{1}x & c_{1}\\
    a_{2} & b_{2}x & c_{2}\\
    a_{3} & b_{3}x& c_{3}\\
    \end{bmatrix}\right)
$$

I've tried using the multilinearity of the determinant, but i didn't get very far and now im stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\left|\begin{matrix}
a_1+b_1x & a_1-b_1x & c_1\\
a_2+b_2x & a_2-b_2x & c_2\\
a_3+b_3x & a_3-b_3x & c_3
\end{matrix}\right|$

$=\;\; \left|\begin{matrix}
a_1 & a_1-b_1x & c_1\\
a_2 & a_2-b_2x & c_2\\
a_3 & a_3-b_3x & c_3
\end{matrix}\right|+\left|\begin{matrix}
b_1x & a_1-b_1x & c_1\\
b_2x & a_2-b_2x & c_2\\
b_3x & a_3-b_3x & c_3
\end{matrix}\right|$

$=\;\; \left|\begin{matrix}
a_1 & a_1 & c_1\\
a_2 & a_2 & c_2\\
a_3 & a_3 & c_3
\end{matrix}\right|+\left|\begin{matrix}
a_1 & -b_1x & c_1\\
a_2 & -b_2x & c_2\\
a_3 & -b_3x & c_3
\end{matrix}\right|+\left|\begin{matrix}
b_1x & a_1 & c_1\\
b_2x & a_2 & c_2\\
b_3x & a_3 & c_3
\end{matrix}\right|+\left|\begin{matrix}
b_1x & -b_1x & c_1\\
b_2x & -b_2x & c_2\\
b_3x & -b_3x & c_3
\end{matrix}\right|
$

$=\;\; 0+\left|\begin{matrix}
a_1 & -b_1x & c_1\\
a_2 & -b_2x & c_2\\
a_3 & -b_3x & c_3
\end{matrix}\right|+\left|\begin{matrix}
b_1x & a_1 & c_1\\
b_2x & a_2 & c_2\\
b_3x & a_3 & c_3
\end{matrix}\right|+0
$

$=\;\; -x \left|\begin{matrix}
a_1 & b_1 & c_1\\
a_2 & b_2 & c_2\\
a_3 & b_3 & c_3
\end{matrix}\right|+ x\left|\begin{matrix}
b_1 & a_1 & c_1\\
b_2 & a_2 & c_2\\
b_3 & a_3 & c_3
\end{matrix}\right|
$

$=\;\; -x \left|\begin{matrix}
a_1 & b_1 & c_1\\
a_2 & b_2 & c_2\\
a_3 & b_3 & c_3
\end{matrix}\right|-x \left|\begin{matrix}
a_1 & b_1 & c_1\\
a_2 & b_2 & c_2\\
a_3 & b_3 & c_3
\end{matrix}\right|
$

$=\;\; -2x \left|\begin{matrix}
a_1 & b_1 & c_1\\
a_2 & b_2 & c_2\\
a_3 & b_3 & c_3
\end{matrix}\right|
$

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed multilinearity you want to use. Write
$$
a =
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}\\
a_{2}\\
a_{3}
\end{bmatrix},
\quad
b =
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}\\
b_{2}\\
b_{3}
\end{bmatrix},
\quad
c =
\begin{bmatrix}
c_{1}\\
c_{2}\\
c_{3}
\end{bmatrix},
$$
then
\begin{align*}
\det(\begin{bmatrix}a + b x & a - b x & c\end{bmatrix})
&=
\det(\begin{bmatrix}a & a & c\end{bmatrix})
- x^{2}
\det(\begin{bmatrix}b & b & c\end{bmatrix})
\\&- x
\det(\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c\end{bmatrix})
+ x
\det(\begin{bmatrix}b & a & c\end{bmatrix}).
\end{align*}

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm still a bit confused as to how you added up the submatrices

Comment: I am only using the fact that you mentioned, that is, that the determinant is multilinear, that is, linear in each column, plus the fact that it is an alternating function of the columns.